# Removing dates and all junks from texts using R

Tags: r, regex, text, data-cleaning, gsub

I am cleaning a huge dataset made up of tens of thousands of texts using R. I know regular expression will do the job conveniently but I am poor in using it. I have combed stackoverflow but could not find solution. This is my dummy data:

```
foo_data <- c("03 / 05 / 2016 Education is good: WO0001982", 
              "04/02/2016 Health is a priority: WAI000553",
              "09/ 08/2016 Economy is bad: 2031CE8D", 
              ": : 21 / 05 / 13: Vehicle license is needed: DPH2790 ")
```

I want to remove all the dates, punctuations and IDs and want my result to be this:

```
[1] "Education is good"        
[2] "Health is a priority"     
[3] "Economy is bad"           
[4] "Vehicle license is needed"
```

Any help in R will be appreciated.

Comment: Do any of the offered answers resolve your issue, William?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think specificity is in order here:

First, let's remove the date-like strings. I'll assume either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`, where the first two can be 1-2 digits, and the third is always 4 digits. If this is variable, the regex can be changed to be a little more permissive:

```r
foo_data2 <- gsub("\\d{1,2}\\s*/\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*/\\s*\\d{4}", "", foo_data)
foo_data2
# [1] " Education is good: WO0001982"        " Health is a priority: WO0002021"     " Economy is bad: WO001999"            " Vehicle license is needed: WO001050"
```

From here, the abbreviations seem rather easy to remove, as the other answers have demonstrated. You have not specified if the abbreviation is hard-coded to be anything after a colon, numbers prepended with `"WO"`, or just some one-word combination of letters and numbers. Those could be:

```r
gsub(":.*", "", foo_data2)
# [1] " Education is good"         " Health is a priority"      " Economy is bad"            " Vehicle license is needed"
gsub("\\bWO\\S*", "", foo_data2)
# [1] " Education is good: "         " Health is a priority: "      " Economy is bad: "            " Vehicle license is needed: "
gsub("\\b[A-Za-z]+\\d+\\b", "", foo_data2)
# [1] " Education is good: "         " Health is a priority: "      " Economy is bad: "            " Vehicle license is needed: "
```

The `:` removal should be straight forward, and using `trimws(.)` will remove the leading/trailing spaces.

This can obviously be combined into a single regex (using the logical `|` with pattern grouping) or a single R call (nested `gsub`) without complication, I kept them broken apart for discussion.

I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 is a good reference for regex in general, note that while that page shows many regex things with single-backslashes, R requires all of those use double-backslashes (e.g., `\d` in regex needs to be `\\d` in R). The exception to this is if you use R-4's new raw-strings, where these two are identical:

```r
"\\b[A-Za-z]+\\d+\\b"
r"(\b[A-Za-z]+\d+\b)"
```

Comment: hi @r2evans, your answer looks good. However, can you modify the code to deal with situation whereby symbols are not hard-coded and dates not in the right format. I have modified the original question to reflect my question. Thanks.

Comment: `gsub("^[ :]*|:[^:]*$", "", gsub("\\d{1,2}\\s*/\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*/\\s*\\d{2}(\\d{2})?", "", foo_data))`

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. It looks okay in the dummy dataset but in the large dataset, not all abbreviations were removed, though date-like strings were removed. Abbreviations such as ```"11D2013A"```, ```"MLY3595"```, ```"WAI004882", "4Fun"``` were not removed from ```c("Education,  support - 11D2013A",  "- MLY3595 - Breast Feeding",
  "WAI004882",  "Chevy -   - 4Fun Literacy and Numeracy")```.  The expected result should be ```"Education,  support", "Breast Feeding", NA, "Literacy and Numeracy"```. Any help ll be appreciated.

Comment: I can only work on what I "know". Perhaps you can add a few more examples that clearly communicate the difference and evidence the over-selection in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using stringr try this:

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

str_remove_all(foo_data, "\\/|\\d+|\\: WO") %>% 
  str_squish()

#> [1] "Education is good"         "Health is a priority"     
#> [3] "Economy is bad"            "Vehicle license is needed"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
foo_data <- c("03 / 05 / 2016 Education is good: WO0001982", "04/02/2016 Health is a priority: WO0002021",
              "09/ 08/2016 Economy is bad: WO001999", "09/08/ 2016 Vehicle license is needed: WO001050")
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
foo_data <- c("03 / 05 / 2016 Education is good: WO0001982", "04/02/2016 Health is a priority: WO0002021",
              "09/ 08/2016 Economy is bad: WO001999", "09/08/ 2016 Vehicle license is needed: WO001050")
gsub(".*\\d{4}[[:space:]]+(.*):.*", "\\1", foo_data)
#> [1] "Education is good"         "Health is a priority"     
#> [3] "Economy is bad"            "Vehicle license is needed"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>