# R: Excluding diversity of junks from text data

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning, stringr, data-wrangling

I have a huge text dataset with diverse junks. The dummy data below is a representative of diversity of junks in the dataset. While `outcome` column contains data to be cleaned, the `text_group` column shows types of junks.  The `clean_outcome` is the result desired.

```
foo_df <- tibble(outcome = c(
  "Dwayne Mourinho : PPP : 22/05/16 : WCY011068",
  "Sarry Bedford : FamSuppr : 14/06/16 : ZAK0",
  "Awanui Moutinho : FamChild : 14/02/14 : BAS007083",
  "Allyson Bosere : Budgetng : 03/08/16 : XAP005407",
  "Anneke Peter : PAFT : 17/12/12 : MAI005518",
  "Budget for the Math",
  "Parenting programs",
  "WINZ",
  "IRD",
  "Baby First Aid Cert. - 00BC61FB",
  "Stop taking drugs - 81868C49",
  "Pamela Riri - LBM2925 - Breast Feeding",
  "Afunbiowo Ige - GMY3480 - AOD",
  "Paora Fowler - Literacy & Numeracy",
  "Yang Wilson - Literacy & Numeracy",
  "Samuel Bell - Literacy & Numeracy",
  "COVID-19 Outcome - Johnson Buhari",
  "Positive Parenting Programme (Triple P)-Kanu Babayaro",
  "Goals : Wx000371",
  "Mentoring : WO000372",
  NA
),
text_group = c(
  1,1,1,1,1,
  2,2,2,2,
  3,3,
  4,4,
  5,5,5,
  6,6,
  7,7,
  8
),
clean_outcome = c(
  "PPP",
  "FamSuppr",
  "FamChild",
  "Budgetng",
  "PAFT",
  "Budget for the Math",
  "Parenting programs",
  "WINZ",
  "IRD",
  "Baby First Aid Cert.",
  "Stop taking drugs",
  "Breast Feeding",
  "AOD",
  "Literacy & Numeracy",
  "Literacy & Numeracy",
  "Literacy & Numeracy",
  "COVID-19 Outcome",
  "Positive Parenting Programme (Triple P)",
  "Goals",
  "Mentoring",
  NA)
)
```

I found contributions from [stackoverflowpage1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208442/removing-dates-and-all-junks-from-texts-using-r/67218480?noredirect=1#comment120137113_67218480) and [stackoverflowpage2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915806/remove-both-english-and-non-english-names-from-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment120042764_67915806) to be partly useful but still do not completely clean the data (i.e. `outcome`).

After thorough study of `outcome`, I observe the following narrative:

> ##### if the text has date, the delimiter is colon and the data is between the 1st and 2nd delimiter
>
> ##### if the text has one dash delimiter, with no name, the data is before the delimiter
>
> ##### In most cases, if the text has one dash delimiter, with name, the data is after the delimiter
>
> ##### if the text has two dash delimiter, the data is after the second delimiter
>
> ##### if the text has one colon delimiter, the data is after the delimiter

This function:

```
colon_function <-  function(x){
if(str_count(x, ":") == 3) {
  trimws(str_split(x, ":")[[1]][[2]])
}else x}
```

cleans the data if the text has date, and the delimiter is colon and the data is between the 1st and 2nd delimiter (i.e. `foo_df$text_group == 1`).

I need help to be include other conditions in an R code, such that I can have a result such as in `clean_outcome`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a known list of clean outcomes?

Comment: Thanks @Elin, the expected clean outcome is already in the ```clean_outcome``` column in dummy dataframe ```foo_df``` provided in the question. The text to be cleaned is in ```outcome``` column.

Comment: So you will never have any other values?  In that case it will be simpler to search the strings for the fixed lists.    Also if you know that 100% the patterns you have shown will be followed you can work out logically the order to do the cleaning in.